# How do I insert X-PAYPAL headers with Rails Invoice SDK?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sdk, paypal

I'm using the paypal SDK for invoicing located here:
https://github.com/paypal/invoice-sdk-ruby

This works great.

I integrated the paypal permissions SDK for rails:
https://github.com/paypal/permissions-sdk-ruby

The authorization workflow is working great.

So now I need to put them together.  The documentation for the permissions sdk leaves off after you get your token.  It doesn't explain how to use it with the other paypal SDKs (at least not so I could understand :D )  The invoice sdk tells you to see the Auth sdk.

Paypal tells me:

```
# Third-party Auth headers
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SUBJECT:<receiverEdress>"  # Merchant's PayPal e-mail
-H "X-PAYPAL-AUTHENTICATION:<OAuthSig>"          # Generated OAuth Signature
```

Don't know how to insert that.  The request is generated here in my model:

```
    @create_and_send_invoice = api.build_create_and_send_invoice(paypalized || default_api_value)
```

The data itself is assembled in the invoice model like so:

```
paypalized = {
:access_token => self.user.paypal_token, 
:invoice => {
  :merchantEmail => self.user.paypal_email || self.user.email,
  :payerEmail => self.client.email,
  :itemList => @itemlist,
  :currencyCode => "USD",
  :paymentTerms => "DueOnReceipt",
  :invoiceDate => self.updated_at,
  :number => self.name,
  :note => self.description,
  :merchantInfo => @businessinfo
  # project / Invoice title?
 } # end invoice
} # end paypalized
return paypalized
```

This implementation is not working and the access_token field is being rejected.  I looked through the gems associated with the sdks but can't see where the headers themselves are built or how to interact with that.

UPDATE: Found this which gives me a clue...

```
       INVOICE_HTTP_HEADER = { "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-SOURCE" => "invoice-ruby-sdk-#{VERSION}" }
```

This seems to be used here during calls in the paypal-sdk-invoice gem:

```
    # Service Call: CreateAndSendInvoice
  # @param CreateAndSendInvoiceRequest
  # @return CreateAndSendInvoiceResponse
  def CreateAndSendInvoice(options = {} , http_header = {})
    request_object  = BuildCreateAndSendInvoice(options)
    request_hash    = request_object.to_hash
    ...
```

I notice that there's two arguments: options and http_header.  It's possible I can modify the http_header argument and pass it this way in my controller:

```
@create_and_send_invoice_response = api.create_and_send_invoice(@create_and_send_invoice, @cutsom_header)
```

or maybe

```
@create_and_send_invoice = api.build_create_and_send_invoice(data, custom_header)
```

I'll keep this updated since I googled around a lot and couldn't find any clear answers on how to do this...

Comment: `my_header = { 
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SUBJECT" => @invoice.user.email,
        "X-PAYPAL-AUTHENTICATION" => @invoice.user.token 
    }
    @create_and_send_invoice_response = api.create_and_send_invoice(@create_and_send_invoice, my_header)`
    
That did it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `token` and `token_secret` while creating API object for third-party authentication.

```
@api = PayPal::SDK::Invoice::API.new({
   :token => "replace with token",
   :token_secret => "replace with token-secret" })
```